# Python: create json query

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to get python to create a json formatted like :

```
[
    {
        "machine_working": true
    },
    {
        "MachineName": "TBL165-169",
        "MachineType": "Rig Test"
    }
]
```

However, i can seam to do it, this is the code i have currently but its giving me error

```
this_is_a_dict_too=[]
this_is_a_dict_too = dict(State="on",dict(MachineType="machinetype1",MachineName="MachineType2"))
```

> File "c:\printjson.py", line 40
>       this_is_a_dict_too = dict(Statedsf="test",dict(MachineType="Rig Test",MachineName="TBL165-169")) SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after
>   keyword arg

Comment: Did you read the error message? As it tells you, you have a non-keyword (i.e. positional) argument after the `State` keyword argument. More broadly, your `this_is_a_dict_too` is initially **not** a dict, and by the looks of your expected output shouldn't be, and `'State' != 'machine_working'`.

Comment: That's two dictionaries in a *list*.

Comment: that's not how you create dictionaries in python, you should read up more on the basics : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know what the message meant.  I'm currently reading the link @AntiMatterDynamite posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
this_is_a_dict_too = [dict(machine_working=True),dict(MachineType="machinetype1",MachineName="MachineType2")]
print(this_is_a_dict_too)
```

Comment: You should add comments explaining why you recommend the above code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make dictionary in dictionary, the error message say that you try to add element without name (corresponding key)

```
dict(a='b', b=dict(state='on'))
```

will work, but

```
dict(a='b', dict(state='on'))
```

won't.

The thing that you presented is list, so you can use

```
   list((dict(a='b'), dict(b='a')))
```

Note that example above use two dictionaries packed into tuple.

or

```
  [ dict(a='b'), dict(b='a') ]
```